# Iterating over an Array in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have the following Test collection where each document looks like:

```
firstName: "Jeff",
     lastname: "Harper",
     scores:[ {'period':'week one', 'score':90},
              {'period':'week two', 'score':85},
              {'period':'week three','score':92},
              {'period':'week four', 'score':87}
```

I would like to iterate through the scores array and console.log the score.  As a trial, I have tried:

```
Test.find()forEach(function(doc){ console.log( doc.firstName ) } );
```

This works fine to print out the first name. If I would want to print the first score in the array object, i.e., I try the statement:

```
Test.find()forEach(function(doc){ console.log( doc.scores[0].score ) } );
```

which doesn't work.  How do I gain access to the elements in the array of objects?

Comment: This ought to work fine. I just tested with a similar data structure in my console without problems.  Check your syntax, I see you are missing a period between find() and forEach() in your question.

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work" means in this case. Do you get an error? Without that we can only speculate. Maybe some docs have an empty list of scores?

Comment: Christian--I have not filled out all the documents yet to include a scores array object since there is  a large number.  I wanted to make sure a I had the syntax down first and I just entered a few of the documents with the scores array.  Would this cause the problems?  If so, how do I test the document to make sure it has a scores array object before I process it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your input.  Christian Fritz identified my problem.  Now, I limit my search to only documents that have the object array.  Both the forEach method and the fetch() method work now.  However, Ethaan, I had to include an inner for-loop inside the primary for-loop to gain access to each internal score.  Thanks for your help and your editing and the picture of the beautiful asian princess.